# What works the same as cfinclude in C#?

Tags: c#, coldfusion

In ColdFusion, I could create a page and reference it from other pages within the website by using the [cfinclude](http://cfdocs.org/cfinclude) tag.

I am using C# in Visual Studio 2010 - ASP.NET environment.

What is the equivalent of cfinclude in c#?

Comment: If you want to access code written in other files (classes) then take a look into [namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dfb3cx8s.aspx). If you are creating some sort of web application with C# and you actually mean web pages, then I suggest you include information about how you are doing that, what technologies are you using? (ASP.Net for example) Be more specific about your problem!

Comment: Depending on what these re-useable pages actually do, you may want to put them into a class library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C# uses assemblies to separate code.  The essence being that you add the other assembly as a reference to your second project, and then as musefun states, use the `using` keyword to "import" the relevant namespaces in to a particular .cs file.

Your question mentions pages.  If you're using something like MVC with the razor syntax, you can use partial views to share html across multiple pages.

You can also compile razor views in to a dll and reference them that way (see RazorGenerator) - this enables you to share common views across multiple projects.  Things such as jquery scripts and other common script files can *also* be shared by embedding them as resources within a shared library and writing some boilerplate code to redirect routes to virtual path providers - though that is perhaps beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: Technically, the partial views answer is dead on, but in CF you can also "import" classes/packages into a CF class with the keyword "import", the same as in C#.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably no equivalent to cfinclude in the .net framework.  In ColdFusion, the included file has access to all the variables to the including file.  For example

MainPage.cfm

```
<cfset myVariable = "Have a nice day">
<cfinclude template = "IncludedFile.cfm">
```

IncludedFile.cfm

```
<cfoutput>#myVariable#</cfoutput>
```

will display "Have a nice day".

I've only done a bit of .net stuff, but I have not seen anything where 1 file inherits variables from another.

That does not mean that you can't re-use code in .net.  It just means that you have to do it another way.

Comment: Thanks so much Dan.  I am trying to accept both your answer and Moo-Juice's answer but it is only letting me select one answer.  I will check the tips to see how to accept both as answers.

Comment: Don't worry about it.  His answer is better anyway.